# HTML Divs show/hide issue

Tags: javascript, jsp

Hi friends I have issue with divs.
I have a link show/hide dive on my page on clicking which i have to show or hide specific divs.
I am successful with doing it.
But my issue is that whenever I click on that link div is get hide or shown but page get directly on the top & I have to scroll to down again.
I don't want to scroll this and don't want to get to top.

Please help me out with this.
Thank You in advance.

Update:
Friend I got the answer from one of my friend.
Actually I was using 
Because of href="#" URL get changed and page got to top every time I click on that link.

Comment: Can you post your sample code or create jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="container">

        </div><!-- end of #container div -->

        <a id="showdiv">Show the div</a>|<a id="hideDiv">Hide the div</a>|<a id="toggle">Toggle</a>

    </div><!-- end of #wrapper div -->

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the css:

```
#container {
 width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
   background: red; 
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#wrapper {
 margin: 40px auto;
 width: 400px;
}
```

And here's the jquery

```
$(function() {// When document is ready, run this...

//Get hold of the link with the id #showdiv and do something when you click it
$("#showdiv").click(function() {
    // Grab the div with the id #container and show it
    // Alert me when you're done
    $("#container").show(2000, function() {
        alert("I'm done showing");
    });
});

//Get hold of the link with the id #hideDiv and do something when you click it
$("#hideDiv").click(function() {
    // Grab the div with the id #container and hide it
    // Alert me when you're done
    $("#container").hide(2000, function() {
        alert("I'm done hiding");
    });

});

// Toggle - This is like a On/Off Switch
//Get hold of the link with the id #toggle and do something when you click it
$("#toggle").click(function() {
    // Grab the div with the id #container and show if hidden / hide if shown
    $("#container").toggle(2000);
});

});
```

Of course you'd have to link to a copy of jQuery before using the script above.
Here's a link to a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tonystark/HhNBA/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a link

Inline (not recommended but likely what you have)

```
<script>
function showhide(id) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  elem.style.display=elem.style.display=="none"?"block":"none";
  return false; // MANDATORY
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="return showhide('someId')">Toggle</a>
<div id="someId">Show or hide me when you click a link</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to cancel the default behavior of the `onclick` handler of your link. For doing so, don't use `return false` in your click handler, but rather use `event.preventDefault()`:

HTML:

```
<a href="#targetdiv" class="foo">hide me</a>
<div id="#targetdiv">blah</div>
```

Javascript:

```
document.querySelector('a.foo').onclick = function(event) {
    try {
        document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).style.display = 'none';
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("couldn't find element to hide");
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('a.foo').click(function(event) {
    try {
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("couldn't find element to hide");
    }
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

More informations:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html
- http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: Interesting intro to fairly new selector. [Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector#section_5)

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your link is pointing to something like `#foo` or just `#`, whereas it should not have a `href` (or have an empty one)...

Answer (score 0):

remove the href attribute and apply a text-decoration style

```
<a style="text-decoration: underline;" title="click me"></a>
```

that'd seem to make more sense than applying an href you dont want, to block its normal operation later. an alternative for graceful degradation would be to use the href to point to the shown/hidden div, displaying normally by default and having javascript hide it where javascript is available.

*"Change your anchor (link) to a span so that it doesn't have that behaviour. Then, style it using css so it looks how you want it to look."*

i often use that techique. i.e., use a span or div with an onclick, styled with text-decoration: underline, cursor: pointer and possibly display: inline if you decide on a div.  one caveat is that in IE6, css hover won't work on anything other than an anchor.  that's easily fixed with javascript.

you could probably remove the href attribute completely. anchors have advantages as above (cross-browser :hover styles) and allow for a title attribute for tool tips etc.

Answer (score -1):

you probaby have a # in href attribute like `href=#` please remove hash and instead of that write `href='javascript:void(null);'`

Comment: That is a horrible idea which will give errors if js is off. Instead return false on the onclick event handler

Comment: @mplungjan buddy onclick event handler ? even if js is off?? didnt get you.

Comment: In pragmatic html/javascript the # is IMNHO perfectly ok so you need to have `<a href="#" onclick="whatever(); return false">Click</a>` and not `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="whatever()">Click</a>` because there is no need and it is not degrading gracefully

Comment: ya thats what my point is 'not degrading gracefully' is not clear to me. You are also using the onclick='whatever()' this also i guess wouldnt work in case javascript is disabled.

Comment: But it would not give an error. Yours will try to load a web page called javascript:void...